# OpenFeign - not throw exception for response status 304

Tags: openfeign

I am trying to not raise an exception when response status is 304.

I tried to add a Error Decoder

```
class CustomErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        if (response.status() == 304) {
            // Custom handling for status 304 (Not Modified)
            return null;
        }

        // For other status codes, delegate to the default error decoder
        return defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
    }
}
```

but I end up with a null pointer exception in the lib, because he is trying to decode the body

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot throw exception because the return value of "feign.InvocationContext.decodeError(String, feign.Response)" is null
    at feign.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:72) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:?]
    at feign.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:63) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:114) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70) ~[feign-core-13.1.jar:?]
```

Any work around ?

I guess I can catch the exception, check the response status and if 304 not raise an exception. I'd prefer not end up there.